# How can I obtain the original text of a visual component property?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I would like to be able to read the original text of a component (published) property at runtime after it has been (potentially) changed.

The context is that I'm writing an extension of a translation library that we used in our application. That library is old and not supported by the supplier any more so I am on my own to make it work.

Unfortunately, the way the library is coded makes it impossible to use from an ISAPI Dll (for instance, in an [Intraweb](http://www.atozed.com/IntraWeb/index.en.aspx) application). The dictionary part works but the automated translation component does not (mostly because it tries to overwrite some code section in memory). I'm therefore trying to salvage the parts that works (form translation tools and dictionary storage) while rewriting the part that doesn't (well, only the elements that I'm interested in, really).

I'm, however, stopped by the fact that, once a component text property has been translated, it will not match the original text any more and won't be found in the dictionary.

That code is supposed to work in Delphi 7 although I'm planning to migrate it to XE5 as soon as I have enough time for that.

Comment: Check out this sample http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/VCL.RichEdit_Sample

Comment: This has, like, nothing to do with the question asked

Answer (score 1):

> "Once a component text property has been translated, it will not match
>   the original text any more and won't be found in the dictionary."

Can you keep a separate lookup map yourself, of translated content to original? Add to this any time a string is replaced with its translated content. That way you can go back and forth between the original and translated at will.

In XE5, the easiest way would be to use a TDictionary. In D7, you may have to roll your own container.

Comment: Both solutions are very similar but, frankly, it feels like a bad workaround. If I can't find anything better,m though, I'll implement it.

Comment: What translation library are you using? (That's probably worth adding to the question, btw.) If it's old and unsupported, have you considered moving to another one completely, rather than rescuing small bits of it and using hacks / ugly code like this?

Comment: Not really: it's a dead product anyway. They moved from source translation to resource translation and left their customers in the dust. I had to fix tone of problem with their code over the years so the end result doesn't really looks like the original.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a procedure that save the original values to a List or some array, then call that procedure in the Form's Loaded method (you have to override it, and don't forget to call inherited at the end of it.) Then search for the directory entry in that list. The Form's Loaded method is called after all the components is loaded from the DFM but before the FormCreate. So here you can find all the original properties.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, what you want is to get back the value of string properties as they are stored in the DFM at compile time.

So, I guess the most reliable way to do so would be from the DFM itself. As far as I know, DFMs are always stored inside the binaries as resources (though there might be some exceptions...). I looked into doing something similar a while ago. I didn't manage to make it work as R&D time ran out (I only had a couple of hours), but if you want to look into it, I'd start with

```
TCustomForm.Create
  InitInheritedComponent
    InternalReadComponentRes
      TStream.ReadComponent
        TReader.ReadRootComponent
```

Maybe someone can confirm whether this approach can work or not and what are the caveat, but until then, I think it's a valid research direction for you.